# Concentrating on Allah SWT

Tags: salat, practical-islam, allah

As-salamu Alaykum,

If a mental image of what Allah SWT looks like pops up in your head, even though you know Allah SWT is greater than what any of us can ever imagine, does that make you fall outside of Islam?

Jazak Allah Khair

Answer (score -1):

Waalaikumsalam WBT,

Thinking about Allah S.W.T can be understood in two meanings and ways. Firstly, one thinks about Allah by equalizing Him to the substance and nature of Allah S.W.T. While the second meaning is thinking about Allah S.W.T in the sense that he remembers Him *(zikrullah).*

If we think about Allah by referring Him to substance of God then this is prohibited. Plus, if one pray to the substance of Allah instead to Allah Himself, then this is considered as denial *(kufur).*

However, if one thinks about God by doing *zikrullah* and reciting the Quran then this is demanded and encouraged.

Wallahwualam. Let us pray to Allah S.W.T to give us a good understanding on Islam. Ameen.

Comment: This is very helpful, Jazak Allah.

Answer (score -1):

W'Alaykom A'ssalam

**Short answer**.

> Nothing will make you fall out Islam, except worshiping but ALLAH.

**Long answer**

> Imagining Allah SWT, and what does he may look like or how does he act
>   or even if he actually is there, is called Waswas from Shaitan. You
>   need to To seek refuge from it, and keep your mind busy with other
>   useful things like Zikr and Qur'an.

Comment: As a child I ended up having this image in my mind and only found out recently this is wrong, I try to repel it as much as I can now but sometimes it comes naturally and I get scared...

Comment: @better_destination, most of us never spoke our minds where we were little, that is why we grew up with some different thoughts than what the Truth really is. the problem lies in not trying to normalize those thoughts as we grow up. I think you are doing a good job worrying about that. I'm sure one day ALLAH will reward you with piece of mind and soul. Keep struggling 'this is what life is really all about'.

Comment: Thank you, but it is getting to me. It does stress me because of the fear of doing something wrong :(

Comment: Imagining is not *ACTION* in Islam, you are not doing anything actually. **BUT** it would become **HARAM** only if you did not fight it. You have to struggle to overcome your fears to prove your worthy of Jannah. each Muslim endures burdens equal to what he could overcome. That means ALLAH knows you are strong enough for this.

Comment: But see this confuses me because if I ignore the thoughts then I’m not fighting them, but I’m not accepting them.

Comment: If ignoring those bad thoughts, would make them go away, then it's fine. If you can win without a fight then it's better. But I don't think ignoring them will make them go away.

Comment: I’m just so stressed

Comment: Take it easy and read some Qur'an, you will be fine Insha'ALLAH

Comment: Thank you, In Sha Allah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108889/discussion-between-better-destination-and-evry1falls).